# Populating a Table from a Dict of Pairs (Column Name, Value) and 0 If Not Found - Python and sqlite3

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlite

I have a a dict that contains an itemID as a key and then a bunch of pairs like this:

```
(91311703, [(3300, 2), (3301, 3), (3327, 3), (3330, 2), (3386, 2), (3392, 2), (3
402, 3), (3413, 3), (3426, 3), (3449, 3)])
```

The first number in each pair is a unique ID number and the second number is a value from 1-5.  I want to write this to a table using sqlite3 so that, in this example, there would be one row with an itemID of 91311703 and then a value of 2 in the 3300 column, 3 in the 3301 column, 3 in the 3327 column, etc.

The twist is that the table would have columns for every possible ID number, around 200-300 in total.  If the dict I pass it does not contain an ID number I want it to put a 0 for that column, so in this example columns 3302-3326, 3328, 3329, 3331-3385, etc. would all get a value of 0.

One possibility I've thought of is to create this table with a default value of 0 for each column and then when I pass in the dict it would only update the values for ID number columns that it contains.  This seems like a poorly coded way of doing this, though, so I'm open to suggestions.  Another option is some sort of `if` and `else` that says if ID number is found in the dict then use the value in its pair else use 0, but that also doesn't seem like a really good way of doing this.

What Python + sqlite3 code do I need to look through this dict and assign values to the columns that match the ID number in the pairs in this dict?  What would you suggest for assigning 0 to those columns where the ID number is not found in the dict?  My goal is to have one row per itemID (i.e. 1 row per key in my dict.)

Comment: Why that many columns? That smells of terrible database design to me.

Comment: mgilson - You have a point, I left out something, it's a dict that has an itemID number as the key and then a list that goes with it - updated the post to reflect this.

Martijn Pieters - Well, any given itemID can have between 0 and all of the possible unique IDs in its list of pairs, so this is the way I could think of that could accommodate all possibilities.  My goal is one row per itemID.

Answer (score 1):

You could either crete the SQL dynamically, setting only those columns that are actually needed:

```sql
INSERT INTO MyTable (itemID, col3300, col3301, col3327, col3330, ...)
VALUES (91311703, 2, 3, 3, 2, ...)
```

or use a command with all columns, and set the unused ones to `0`:

```sql
INSERT INTO MyTable (itemID, col3300, col3301, col3302, col3303, ...)
VALUES (91311703, 2, 3, 0, 0, ...)
```

---

However, this table structure will be inefficient if there any many unused values.

When properly normalized, you would have a table with only three columns, which contains all valid combination of the item ID, the ID, and the value:

```sql
INSERT INTO MyTable(itemID, ID, value)
VALUES (91311703, 3300, 2),
       (91311703, 3301, 3),
       (91311703, 3327, 3),
       (91311703, 3330, 2),
       ...
```

---

Which of these organizations is better for you depends on what kind of queries you want to to run.

Comment: One of the first two options is what I was thinking but I'd need to automate it.  The code to do the automation is what I'm looking for.  As for the 3rd option with itemID, ID, value - I have considered this, too, but it makes it a lot less convenient for a human to read the table.  With the first two methods, the information for any itemID is all on one row whereas with the 3rd option the information for any itemID is scattered over as many rows as there are pairs in the dict for that itemID.  Both would be fine for querying, but the 3rd is less handy for a human to look at.

Comment: In any case, upvote because it lays out some options, but I was looking for the ways to go about those options.  For example, what code would I need to read the column's name from the ID and put in the associate values on a new row starting with the itemID?  I have messed with the 3rd option before and I think I know how to code it, but how could I code one of the first two options?

Comment: Comments are not the right place to ask questions; edit your question. And when you wrote "sqlite3 code", did you actually mean "Python code"?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I thought I had already asked this in my question.  The question already reads "What sqlite3 code do I need to look through this dict and assign values to the columns that match the ID number in the pairs in this dict?"  I will edit it to read "What Python + sqlite3 code..." to try to avoid confusion.